# C# check if JSON File contains string

Tags: c#, json, string

I am trying to make it so I can check whether a string is in a json.

For exmaple, in my JSON file exists name = Disp_R, name = Disp_L, name = Disp_C. And whenever Disp is in the string, the whole value should be stored in a list

**Thats how I do it, but it don't work with the regex**

```
 var jTempObj = JObject.Parse(starcInformation.DeviceArray);
 var tempItems = jTempObj.SelectTokens("$..items[?(@.name=='" + xmlInformation.Device + "')]");
            
 foreach (var item in tempItems)
 {
     DeviceList.Add(item["name"].ToString());
 }
```

I hope someone can help me :) Thanks a lot

edit

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppG6a.png)
[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vVDB.png)

Comment: Please post an example of the JSON file.

Comment: added two images

Comment: Please don't add image links - post the contents in your question directly

Comment: Your structure is unclear, but you can take the objects 
var description = jTempObj.youStructFather[i].name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json path supports matching [javascript regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), so something like this should work:

```
var js = "{items:[{'name':'DISP_1'}, {'name':'DISP_2'}, {'name':'sa'}, {'name':'DISP_'}]}";
var result = JObject.Parse(js).SelectTokens("$.items[?(@.name =~ /DISP_.+/)]");
```

Result will contain all tokens prefixed with `DISP_` and having at least one symbol after it.

Comment: maybe you can help me a second time. How is the regex if I want the Content of each 'name' ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @TheMan not sure I following you.

Comment: I want the content of each name-token. In your example --> DISP_1, DISP_2, sa,  DISP_. Filter by content with regexes

Comment: @TheMan Sounds like another question)

Comment: @Guro Stron: follow up Question :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573042/c-sharp-get-all-items-from-json-file

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify json using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)
```

than you can find specific string inside it using

```
if(str.Contains("--your-string---"))
```