# C# get all Items from JSON File

Tags: c#, json, regex

this is a follow-up question to a other question from me
[C# check if JSON File contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510515/c-sharp-check-if-json-file-contains-string/62511737?noredirect=1#comment110904423_62511737)

I would prefer a solution with javascript regexes :)

**Sample**

Result of this example will contain all tokens prefixed with DISP_ and having at least one symbol after it.

```
var js = "{items:[{'name':'DISP_1'}, {'name':'DISP_2'}, {'name':'sa'}, {'name':'DISP_'}]}"; 
var result = JObject.Parse(js).SelectTokens("$.items[?(@.name =~ /DISP_.+/)]");
```

now I want the content of each "name" token. In this example --> DISP_1, DISP_2, sa, DISP_. Filter with regexes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd recommend writing code to drill down through the JSON as opposed to using regular expressions to recognise tokens.

Comment: Not sure what do you actually need here. If you just need all `name`'s then you don't need regex, if you want names with specific rule - you should specify this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With deserialization you can go much easier for other developers who will read and maintain this code.

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class AllItems
{
     public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllItems>(js).items
    .Select(item => item.name)
    .ToArray();
```

or to check if some token exists in the json

```
var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllItems>(js).items
    .Select(item => item.name)
    .ToHashSet();

if (tokens.Contains("some_token"))
{
    // Token exists in the json string
}
```

if you check for existence only once then

```
var exists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllItems>(js).items
    .Any(item => item.name == "some_token");

if (exists)
{
    // Token exists in the json string
}
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you